# How to retrieve list of array values in drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to populate list of values in drop down list.

Here is my code which I have tried but I don't know how to proceed with list of array values.  Please suggest so that I can complete my task.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function populate_dropdown(country)
{
    switch(country)
    {
        case "america":
            document.forms[0].states.length = 2;
            document.forms[0].states.disabled = false;
            document.forms[0].states.options[0].text = 'Washington';
            document.forms[0].states.options[0].value = 'Washington';
            document.forms[0].states.options[1].text = 'Florida';
            document.forms[0].states.options[1].value = 'Florida';

            break;
        case "india":
            document.forms[0].states.length = 2;
            document.forms[0].states.disabled = false;
            document.forms[0].states.options[0].text = 'Orissa';
            document.forms[0].states.options[0].value = 'Orissa';
            document.forms[0].states.options[1].text = 'Punjab';
            document.forms[0].states.options[1].value = 'Punjab';
            break;
        default:
            document.forms[0].states.length = 1;
            document.forms[0].states.options[0].text = 'Select a country first';
            document.forms[0].states.disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="this.html" method="post">
<p>
<input id="America" type="radio" name="country" value="America" onclick="populate_dropdown('america')" /><label for="America">America</label><br />
<input id="India" type="radio" name="country" value="India" onclick="populate_dropdown('india')" /><label for="India">India</label><br />

<select disabled="disabled" name="states">
<option>Select a country first</option>
</select>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of the **selected item** from the drop down?

Comment: what is your problem explain it clearly. do you want to add options to select based on click.

Comment: there is no problem with value, I want the value should come from array,in that case,how would I modify the code and how would I retrive the value from array.

Comment: you mean from radio?

Comment: c onclick of radio, value will populate to drop down list, so when populate function is hit, then value should come from array

Comment: which array ?? where it is

Comment: var arrIndia=['ind1','ind2','ind3'];  or var arrIndia=[from database]; how to retrieve the value from array,i just need the clue,and i got it.Thanks Raghavendra. r u from Hyderabad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```js
states = {
    "america": [
        { "text": "Washington", "value": "Washington" },
        { "text": "Florida", "value":  "Florida" },
    ],
    "india": [
        { "text": "Orissa", "value": "Orissa" },
        { "text": "Punjab", "value": "Punjab" },
    ],
};

function populate_dropdown(country) {
    if(!states[country]) {
        document.forms[0].states.options = [];
        document.forms[0].states.disabled = true;
        return;
    }
    
    document.forms[0].states.options.length = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < states[country].length; i++) {
        var state = states[country][i];
        document.forms[0].states.options[i] = new Option(state.text, state.value, false, false);
    }
    document.forms[0].states.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<form action="this.html" method="post">
    <p>
        <input id="America" type="radio" name="country" value="America" onclick="populate_dropdown('america')" />
        <label for="America">America</label>
        <br />
        <input id="India" type="radio" name="country" value="India" onclick="populate_dropdown('india')" />
        <label for="India">India</label>
        <br />
        <select disabled="disabled" name="states">
            <option>Select a country first</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can Use below Updated Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function populate_dropdown(country)
     {
        e=document.forms[0].states;
         switch(country)
         {
             case "america":
                 document.forms[0].states.length = 2;
                 document.forms[0].states.disabled = false;
                 document.forms[0].states.options[0].text = 'Washington';
                 document.forms[0].states.options[0].value = 'Washington';
                 document.forms[0].states.options[1].text = 'Florida';
                 document.forms[0].states.options[1].value = 'Florida';
             // current selected value  alert(document.forms[0].states.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
             break;
             case "india":
                 document.forms[0].states.length = 2;
                 document.forms[0].states.disabled = false;
                 document.forms[0].states.options[0].text = 'Orissa';
                 document.forms[0].states.options[0].value = 'Orissa';
                 document.forms[0].states.options[1].text = 'Punjab';
                 document.forms[0].states.options[1].value = 'Punjab';
                 break;
             default:
                 document.forms[0].states.length = 1;
                 document.forms[0].states.options[0].text = 'Select a country first';
                 document.forms[0].states.disabled = true;
         }
     }
        function dropdown_selected_value(){ 
            alert(document.forms[0].states.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
        }
  </script> </head> <body>
  <form action="this.html" method="post">
     <p>
        <input id="America" type="radio" name="country" value="America" onclick="populate_dropdown('america')" /><label for="America">America</label><br />
        <input id="India" type="radio" name="country" value="India" onclick="populate_dropdown('india')" /><label for="India">India</label><br />
        <select disabled="disabled" name="states" onchange="dropdown_selected_value()">
           <option>Select a country first</option>
        </select>
     </p>
  </form> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh,it means lot to me.

Comment: Its my pleasure .. Enjoy d coding.. :)